# Semi-Direct product but not a direct products

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, semidirect-product, direct-product

What is a semi-direct product of two groups? What is an example of a semi-direct product that is not a direct product?

From what I read in the textbook, a semi-direct product N $\rtimes_\alpha$ A, contains A and N as subgroups with N normal. N $\cap$ A = {$e$},
  N$\times$A= N$\rtimes_\alpha$A  and there is a commutation relation $a_n = \alpha_a(n)a$ where $a\in A$, $n\in N$.
$(n,a)(n',a')=(n\alpha_a(n'),aa')$.

Is this correct? Also, that a direct product is just a special case of a semi-direct product. How would I find an example of a semi-direct product that is not a direct product ?

Comment: In a direct product $H \times K$, **both** $H$ and $K$ are normal.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Shaun The textbook is Algebra: Abstract and Concrete by Frederick Goodman

Comment: I think it would be easier if you focused on just one question.

Answer (score 2):

One simple example is the [dihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group).

As a special case, the symmetric group $S_3$ is isomorphic to $D_3$.